# Is there a way to create an onclick event on my button?

Tags: java, javafx

This is my fxml file and i made an eventlistener for my button with the id of "deletebutton":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox minHeight="600.0" minWidth="800.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" fx:controller="com.example.carjava.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="deleteButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Törlés" />
      <TableView fx:id="carTable" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="licensePlateCol" prefWidth="180.0" text="Rendszám" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="modelCol" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="180.0" text="Model" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="brandCol" prefWidth="180.0" text="Márka" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="dailyCostCol" prefWidth="180.0" text="Napidíj (Ft)" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

I tried making an event listener but i was hoping for something simpler. And also is there a way of making a GUI faster and simpler?

Comment: *"And also is there a way of making a GUI faster and simpler?"* => Yes, but that is both a much too generic question to get an answer here and completely unrelated to your actual question title.

Comment: *"Is there a way to create an onclick event on my button?"* -> You can create a click event for a button by clicking on it, or by [firing](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/event/Event.html#fireEvent(javafx.event.EventTarget,javafx.event.Event)) a [`MOUSE_CLICKED`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_CLICKED) event on the button.  But I have a feel that isn't what you really want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onAction` attribute of the button to bind the click to a method of your controller.

In your FXML :

```
<Button fx:id="deleteButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Törlés" onAction="#onDeleteButtonClicked" />
```

In your controller `HelloController` :

```
public void onDeleteButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
   ...
}
```

Regarding the question "is there a way of making a GUI faster and simpler?", you could use [SceneBuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Comment: Doesn't the method declaration need an `@FXML` annotation?

Comment: @trashgod Not if it's `public`. (Whether or not it should be `public` is another question, though.)

Comment: @James_D: thank you for commenting; slaw's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61044906/230513) elaborates.